# How to reach members of json with iOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I want to reach from ios to a .net .asmx web service, and I reach with the following code:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.****.com/Mobile.asmx/HelloWorld";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSError *errorReturned = nil;
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];
if (errorReturned)
{
    //...handle the error
}
else
{
    NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", retVal);
    //...do something with the returned value


}
```

It returns clean json  `{"hellom":"Hello World","hellom2":"HelloWorld2"}` but I can't reach members and value one by one

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert JSON data into an object by using the following code...

```
NSData *jsonData = ... the data you got from the server

NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

object will then be a NSDictionary like this...

```
@{
    hellom : @"Hello World",
    hellom2: @"HelloWorld2"
}
```

You can then get to the keys and values like any other dictionary.

Comment: Then just get the first member from the dictionary. `object[@"hellom"]`

Comment: There is no "first", or "second, etc., element in a `NSDictionary` since it is an _unordered_ container. You cannot access the elements via an index, like for a `NSArray`, instead you access them by their key. The documentation to `NSDictionary` contains this and more useful info.